# How to resolve Deserialization of untrusted data checkmarx scan issue

Tags: java, checkmarx

I have an checkmarx high defect to resolve deserialization of untrusted data.

Here is my code

```
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file):
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
Object result = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Comment: https://snyk.io/blog/serialization-and-deserialization-in-java/ might help you to understand the issue.

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html, particularly Guideline 8-6.

Comment: @user3291914 is it really untrusted data that will be read? If this code is not used on a public portal, and even limited to authorized users, then one might say it is not a high issue, but rather a medium issue.  Other things you could do is validate the contents (length, filetype, etc.).